# Laravel data recording with API

Tags: laravel, api

I save the received data from the API to the database. In my API result, there is the following answer:

```
"opponents": [
{
"opponent": {
"acronym": "RH",
"id": 127276,
"image_url": "/image/127276/reverse_heaven_logo_std.png",
"location": null,
"modified_at": "2020-04-14T19:03:48Z",
"name": "Reverse Heaven",
"slug": "reverse-heaven"
},
"type": "Team"
},
{
"opponent": {
"acronym": " neon",
"id": 2061,
"image_url": "/image/2061/neon_esport.png",
"location": "PH",
"modified_at": "2020-04-14T19:04:02Z",
"name": "Neon Esports",
"slug": "neon-esports"
},
"type": "Team"
}
],
```

If i use `var_dump($opponents)`, i receive only last `opponent` from API. How can I save exactly 2 values that are in the array under the same name `opponent->name`?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using laravel, you may use collections.

```
$decoded = json_decode($opponents);

return collect($decoded->opponents)->pluck('opponent.name')->toArray();
```

you may do it in a single line if you prefer;

```
return collect(json_decode($opponents)->opponents)->pluck('opponent.name')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

first decode the json like this

```
$decoded_opponents = json_decode($opponents);
```

then create a empty array

```
$array = [];
```

run a foreach loop on you decoded data

```
foreach($decoded_opponents->opponents as $key=>$value){
    $array[]=$value->opponent->name;
}
```

the names now stored in $array